# Java Class Access

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to restrict access of one class by another class with same package?

For eg, we have two class A and B in same package. I want to restrict to instantiate Class A in Class B. Is it possible?

```
public class A
{
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A(); // Shuold not allow to create object of A
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that no other class can initiate it? Something like a private constructor? Or only in the same package?

Comment: Put the two in a separate package, make class `A`'s constructor package private and create a `public createA()` method in class `B` that instantiates `A` objects.

Comment: I do not want to allow create object in class B. Class A should not have private constructor.

Comment: Your question is very poorly worded. Who should be able to instantiate class `A`?

Comment: `I want to restrict to instantiate Class A in Class B`  Means only for `B`.?

Comment: I dont think that is possible to restrict the instantiate for only one class in the SAME package. Can you explain the reason for it ?

Comment: What's your use case? I can't imagine a situation where this would be useful.

Comment: for eg, if a Class is default access level and it is some other package, we cant access that class right. I want the same case but if both classes are in same package. my question is "is it possible or not?"

Comment: NOT possible for ONLY ONE class in the same package. For all classes => private constructor. I think there is not a use case for it...

Answer (score 2):

This would be a special relationship between class A and class B. So either

- class A specifies "I don't allow B to instantiate me" or
- class B specifies "I must not instantiate A"

Both specifications are not possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 4 classes A, B, C & D. A can be accessible to C & D, but not to B.

**NOTE :** A, B & C are in **abc package**. D is in **d package**.

**Step 1 : Make Class A's constructor private**

```
public class A {
    private A() {
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Step 2 : Instantiate A in B.** Gives you the error **The constructor A() is not visible.**

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

**Step 3 : Instantiate A in C**. Gives result **"Hello"**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Constructor<A> constructor = A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);

            A a = constructor.newInstance();
            a.hello();

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4 : Now Instantiate A in D (d package).** Also gives result **"Hello"**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import abc.A;
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Constructor<A> constructor = A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);

            A a = constructor.newInstance();
            a.hello();

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is happens because Java provides two different methods to create an object of a class.

1. [getDeclaredConstructor() - API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors%28%29) **Returns only private constructor.**
2. [getConstructors() - API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) **Returns all available constructors private, public, protected & default (Accessible to package only).**

Comment: Have you tried this ? Do you want something like this ?

Answer (score -2):

> When you specify the private keyword in relation to a member of a
>   class, you make that member inaccessible to anyone else, and the
>   consumers of your library are restricted from using it. This is in
>   effect a way of hiding implementation of the 'parts that change' in
>   your program to give you, as the library creator, the ability to
>   modify it without impacting on your consumers code. Further, private
>   members of a class are only available to methods within the same class
>   [From here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hellofadude/archive/2013/12/08/controlling-access-implementation-hiding-java) 
>       `package kingsley.java;

```
class Egg {
  private Egg() {
   System.out.println("Egg constructor");
  }
  static Egg makeEgg() {
    System.out.println("in makeEgg()");
    return new Egg();
  }
}

public class Breakfast () {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Egg egg1 = new Egg(); //! Error can not Make new Eggs
     Egg egg2 = Egg.makeEgg();
  }
}`
```

Comment: OK, so show some example code that achieves what op wants please.